# VBA code query for automatic populating a cell based on another column's cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a worksheet which has records of customers and their vehicles. In the vehicle details, I have column F which says its Petrol car, Column G which says it is Diesel car. Now i have already put data validation on these two columns to display Y and N. Thus the customers can select either Y or N. I want to write a VBA code for, if the customer selects Y in Column F (Petrol car) then Column G (Diesel Car) should automatically take value N for that customer. If the customer enters Y for Column G then Column F should automatically become N.

Similarly, column H stands for Petrocard and column I stands for Smartfleet. Like above at a time only either of them will take value Y and other will take value N. Here also i have done data validation to give a drop down list of Y and N

Similarly, column J stands for Two wheeler and column K stands for Any other vehicle. Like above at a time only either of them will take value Y and other will take value N. Here also i have done data validation to give a drop down list of Y and N.

In addition to this in this worksheet I have already used a VBA code for another column C (Mobile number) to NOT allow duplicate entries in the excel sheet.

This whole exact process is repeated from Column M to R and from Column T to Y.

Comment: Why not just populate all those cells with an IF statement: Example for G2: IF(F2="","",N) And then for F2 you put in the same formula but then referring to G2. So now as soon as a value is entered in either of the cells, it will replace the formula in that cell and the other cell will get the N value.

Answer (score 0):

Luuklag’s solution is easy to implement and will work well providing the user never places “Y” in the wrong column.

Consider: the user enters “Y” into cell F20, the formula in cell G20 will display “N”.  The user then realises they have made a mistake and enters “Y” into cell G20. The formula in cell F20 has been overwritten so will continue to display “Y”.

You need a `Sheet_Change` or `Change event` routine.

Create a new workbook and open the Visual Basic Editor.  Down the left you will see something like:

```
- VBAProject (Test.xlsm)
   - Microsoft Excel Objects
        Sheet1 (Sheet1)
        Sheet2 (Sheet2)
        Sheet3 (Sheet3)
        ThisWorkbook
```

If either of the hyphens is a plus, click it to expand the list.

Double click `Sheet2 (Sheet2)` to display the code area for worksheet “Sheet2”.  Copy the following to that code area:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Debug.Print Target.Address & "=" & Target.Value

End Sub
```

Switch to Excel and enter a few values into each of the worksheets.  Switch back to Visual Basic and the Immediate Window will contain something like:

```
$E$4=a 
$E$7=b
$H$7=g
$H$4=h
```

None of the values you entered into “Sheet1” or “Sheet3” will be recorded.  For each value you entered into “Sheet2”. You will have a line showing the address of the cell changed and its new value.

There is a similar `Workbook_SheetChange` which goes in the `ThisWorkbook` code area and which would record changes for all worksheets but I think the slightly simpler `Worksheet_Change` routine will be adequate for your needs.

With a `Worksheet_Change` routine you can specify that if a cell in column F becomes “Y”, the matching cell in column G becomes “N”.  And vice versa.

There are two complications:

- With `Worksheet_Change`, `Target` is a range which can include several cells if the user copies a block.  I have used `For Each CellCrnt In Target` to split a range into individual cells.
- You have nine pairs of columns.  It would be possible to code each pair separately but that would be a lot of code.  I have used two arrays.  The first array contains all the columns into which a value might be entered and the second contains the matching columns.  I believe I have recorded your column numbers correctly but they are easily changed if I have made any mistakes.  Using arrays like this means more column pairs can be added just by adding values to the arrays and the columns do not have to be adjacent.

Try my code and come back with questions as necessary.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim CellCrnt As Range
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColsA As Variant
  Dim ColsB As Variant
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim InxCols As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  ColsA = Array(6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 7, 9, 11, 14, 16, 18, 21, 23, 25)
  ColsB = Array(7, 9, 11, 14, 16, 18, 21, 23, 25, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24)

  For Each CellCrnt In Target
    ColCrnt = CellCrnt.Column
    Found = False
    ' Look along ColsA for the column of the cell just changed
    For InxCols = LBound(ColsA) To UBound(ColsA)
      If ColsA(InxCols) = ColCrnt Then
        Found = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    If Found Then
      ' The cell is within a controlled column
      If UCase(CellCrnt.Value) = "Y" Or UCase(CellCrnt.Value) = "N" Then
        RowCrnt = CellCrnt.Row
        ' Good value
        CellCrnt.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)  ' Set Black in case of earlier error
        With Cells(RowCrnt, ColsB(InxCols))
          .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)  ' Set Black in case of earlier error
          If UCase(CellCrnt.Value) = "Y" Then
            .Value = "N"
          Else
            .Value = "Y"
          End If
        End With
      Else
        ' Bad value
        CellCrnt.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)  ' Set Red to indicate error
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```